# I don't have ribbon cable for GPIO, and I need to use a bunch of jumper wires

Tags: gpio, rpi.gpio, pigpio, pi-gpio

I wanna use individual jumper wires but I don't know how to connect them properly to my raspberry.
I'm using the red T-shaped GPIO extension board and raspberry pi 3, I already put all my wires in the T GPIO extension but i don't know which vertical side connect which what side from raspberry please enlight me, i don't want to mess up the raspberry pi

also, do I need to install a code for using the T-Shaped gpio extension into my raspberry? I wanna connect after that the small LCD and also a heat sensor

thanks for the help in advance

right now it looks like this [image]

[image]

Comment: I checked online, but everywhere I search they just use the ribbon cables so i don't really know how to connect them sorry, I'm really new to this

Comment: a ribbon cable is a bunch of wires that have not been physically separated ... in the bottom picture you could easily peel the brown wire away from the cable, and you would have a single jumper wire

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking or what you are trying to do. If you don't have a ribbon cable (they are readily available) DON'T USE a Pi Cobbler. I haven't used one in 10 years of Pi. Just connect the pins you plan to use.
WARNING - it is possible to use 2 cables as pictured BUT be careful - this needs CAREFUL checking and increases the risk of getting things catastrophically wrong.

Comment: Search for “dupont cables”